# mkfs for a new file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel

Hi I have created a new file system say with name"ntr". After initializing the module (insmod) filesystem name is getting displayed in /proc/filesystems. Now I want this file system to be mounted on my pendrive. I tried mkfs, but as mkfs.ntr doesnot exist, I was unsuccessful. Can someone please tell me how to create mkfs.ntr?

Comment: You can write a kernel module for a FS but you can't write a tool to create same FS?

Answer (score 3):

If you wrote a filesystem driver, only you know how to initialize its metadata.  You should probably first start with making a standalone program that operates on a block device, and once that works, integrate it with the `mkfs` tool.

Answer (score 0):

well these are two separated things. mkfs.ext4 for example is a link to mke2fs in /sbin folder. and mke2fs is a tool for creating filesystems. it comes with [e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) package. if you want to have a tool to create your filesystem, well... you can make it and/or add the structure of your filesystem to e2fsprogs.